# Loading built-in Python Wrappers in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, swig, bazel

I'm trying to understand the complete process of exposing the built-in low-level C++ implementations to the Python API in TensorFlow. I've been looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), and I think I get the big picture, however, there is a step where I get stuck. Here what I made out so far:

(1) TensorFlow uses SWIG to automatically generate Python Wrappers given interface files.

(2) Bazel is used to compile the Python Wrappers into .so libraries

I can't figure out Step (3) which is how/where the .so libraries get loaded into the tensorflow framework so that it is possible to do `from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_math_ops` in [math_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py) for example.

Appreciate the hints!

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you may already know the answers. I had the problem installing TF-Agent or GPU version then the error output revales the error message indicated 1. Full Path 2. Compatiblilites.

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.8, TF, TF-Agent, realted libaries you will have problem install the TF Intel because of the full path name or device compatibilies as Linux behaviour.
I do testing and installing that help my understanding when have a new problem.

Hints: Bazel doesn't work with full path in some environment.